# Three.js application crashes when importing 10mb GLB model

Tags: three.js

I am currently learning three.js and I am running into an issue where my browser responds with: [SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4ImL.png) as soon as a glb model is loading in. The development server does not crash. I tried several different browser and increasing the memory of the development server.
My glb is not tiny, but i am hoping to get this working (glb file size is 10mb).
This is my code to load the model.

```js
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load("./models/model.glb", function (gltf) {
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
}, undefined, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
} );
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF asset in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 I got it fixed. I replaced the material with lower resolution material and it loaded in fine